# How do you order stacked bar categories by size in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder categories in a ggplot bar chart by the size of the variables, with the biggest categories first, followed by increasingly minor ones. I've tried playing with the order in a few ways but only seem to be able to set the order manually which isn't very helpful for big data sets.

For example:
Let's say I have the following data:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
shop    fruit   varieties   km_away
shop1   apple   0   12
                     shop1  banana  0   12
                     shop1  pear    2   12
                     shop1  melon   1   12
                     shop1  orange  1   12
                     shop1  peach   3   12
                     shop1  apricot 6   12
                     shop1  lime    1   12
                     shop2  apple   1   1
                     shop2  banana  0   1
                     shop2  pear    2   1
                     shop2  melon   2   1
                     shop2  orange  5   1
                     shop2  peach   4   1
                     shop2  apricot 11  1
                     shop2  lime    0   1
                     shop3  apple   0   2
                     shop3  banana  1   2
                     shop3  pear    2   2
                     shop3  melon   1   2
                     shop3  orange  4   2
                     shop3  peach   1   2
                     shop3  apricot 11  2
                     shop3  lime    1   2
                     shop4  apple   0   5
                     shop4  banana  0   5
                     shop4  pear    3   5
                     shop4  melon   2   5
                     shop4  orange  6   5
                     shop4  peach   1   5
                     shop4  apricot 9   5
                     shop4  lime    0   5
                     ")
```

I can usefully visualise it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
p <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=reorder(shop, km_away), y=varieties, fill=fruit))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()+scale_fill_brewer(palette="Accent")
p
```

But how do I tell ggplot to plot the apricots first, then the oranges, etc? This will make it much easier to visually compare different categories across shops.

Answer (score 3):

You can first obtain a vector of the categories, ordered by your quantity of interest:

```
fruit_levels <- names(sort(tapply(mydata$varieties, mydata$fruit, sum)))
```

Then, in your call to `ggplot`, map `fill` to a factor variable with the corresponding levels:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mydata, 
    aes(x=reorder(shop, km_away), y=varieties, 
        fill=factor(fruit, levels = fruit_levels)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "fruit", palette="Accent") 
p
```

Output:

[image]

---

*Update.* A more direct route is to re-order the factor levels in your original dataframe, and call `ggplot` as in your original code:

```
mydata$fruit <- reorder(mydata$fruit, mydata$varieties, sum)
p <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=reorder(shop, km_away), y=varieties, fill=fruit))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()+scale_fill_brewer(palette="Accent")
p
```

---

*Update 2.* On older versions of `ggplot2` (pre version 2), try specifying the `order` aesthetic:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=reorder(shop, km_away), 
                               y=varieties, 
                               fill=fruit, order=fruit)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()+scale_fill_brewer(palette="Accent")
p
```

And if you want to reverse the ordering, add a negative sign in front of the ordering variable:

```
reorder(mydata$fruit, -mydata$varieties, sum)
```

Comment: When I enter your code, the fruit are still ordered alphabetically rather than by value. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you run `reorder(mydata$fruit, mydata$varieties, sum)`, does the output report "Levels" in the right order? It should read `Levels: apple banana lime melon peach pear orange apricot`.

Comment: Yes.

reorder(mydata$fruit, mydata$varieties, sum)
 [1] apple   banana  pear    melon   orange  peach   apricot lime    apple   banana  pear    melon   orange  peach   apricot lime    apple  
[18] banana  pear    melon   orange  peach   apricot lime    apple   banana  pear    melon   orange  peach   apricot lime   
attr(,"scores")
  apple  banana    lime   melon   peach    pear  orange apricot 
      1       1       2       6       9       9      16      37 
Levels: apple banana lime melon peach pear orange apricot

Comment: Then when you call `ggplot`, it should be plotting the fills in exactly that order.  Maybe restart R and try running the code again?

Comment: I've run this on two different machines and can't reproduce your plot. Both of your code sections produce the same plot as before attempting the reordering.

Comment: I wonder if this is a `ggplot2` version issue. I see what you're saying; the reordering seems to have no effect when I run the code on `ggplot2` 0.9.3.1. What version of `ggplot2` are you using?

Comment: I'm running ggplot 2.1.0

Comment: Perhaps my update 2 might work for you; see http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=5YRga2ck&version=1 for an example that produces the right plot (on ggplot2 0.9.3.1).  If not, I'm out of ideas.